# Is it possible to use both facebook login and account kit in the same application

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an application that is using facebook login and i wanted to add account kit for anyone who didn't want to use the facebook login or doesn't have a facebook account. The problem is that with account kit you either use the phone number or email and thats all but my User model has fields like name, phone and others. If anyone has done this before then you could please explain the workthrough. I thought of creating a different User model for the account kit login but the idea seems vague. Any help is appreciated.

**Update**
I am using the facebook places API so i need access tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Developers integrate both Facebook Login and Account Kit into their apps. This allows for people to choose their login mechanism and increase user base.

An example case study from Saavn who did this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/case-studies/saavn?__mref=message_bubble

Answer (score -1):

Firebase Authentication is very useful in your case

refer this:https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/

Google Firebase offers many authentication like google ,facebook,twitter and custom authentication also

Comment: Adding firebase would make the application bulky

Comment: I checked here Firebase doesnt support Account-Kit http://stackoverflow.com/a/37060098/3560569